# Change Page Style in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have started building a blog using Orchard CMS. I have setup the CMS and blog feature.But how do i change the style(css,html,javascript) of a specific page.one more thing,i have created a page as home page from dashboard named "orchard_blog".But i cant find any page named "orchard_blog" in web matrix or visual studio solution explorer! 
please help me,it would be very helpful for me!

Comment: A CMS is not a static web site, which means you won't find a html file for all the pages you create. Instead, you create contents that is stored in a database, and then that content gets rendered using templates. In Orchard, you can specialize templates down to single pages, but that's usually not such a good idea. If you explain in a little more details what you're trying to do, I can show you how, but it would probably be a good idea to start with reading Orchard documentation, for instance: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme/

Comment: I want to change the look of a specific page.Every page i create is generated based on the theme.But this is not good looking.I need to stylize the pages as i want.Consider Home Page,i need to change the home page menu-bar,background-color,add a banner etc.Please give a way to do these @BertrandLeRoy

Comment: Yes, you need to learn how to customize a theme (the link I already gave you is a good place to start), and you need to learn about alternates: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/